# How do I put a clock on the desktop background on Ubuntu 19.04, gnome

Tags: clock, widgets

How do I put a clock on the desktop background on Ubuntu 19.04 GNOME

Is there maybe an extension that I am not finding?

I have google all I think is relevant.

Comment: Can you please try the edited code? It should fix the error you saw with `own_window_type = 'override',`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install *conky* by running `sudo apt install conky-all`

Create the folder *conky* in `~/.config`. Then, in `~/.config/conky`, create an empty plain text file called `conky.conf`.

Open a plain text editor, paste the following content into `conky.conf` and save the file:

```
conky.config = {

    background = false,
    update_interval = 1,
    double_buffer = true,
    no_buffers = true,
    text_buffer_size = 2048,
    own_window = true,
    own_window_class = 'conky',
    own_window_argb_visual = true,
    own_window_argb_value = 80,
    own_window_hints = 'undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',
    own_window_colour = '#252525',
    own_window_type = 'desktop',
    background = false,
    minimum_width = 250,
    gap_x = 100,
    gap_y = 200,
    draw_shades = false,
    draw_outline = false,
    draw_borders = false,
    override_utf8_locale = true,
    use_xft = true,
    font = 'Noto:size=8',
    xftalpha = 0.5,
    uppercase = false
};

conky.text = [[
${voffset 5}${offset 15}${font Noto:size=36}${color white}${time %e}
${goto 25}${font Noto:size=18}${color white}${voffset -30}${time %b}${color white}${offset 10}${time %Y}
${font Noto:size=12}${color white}${voffset 5}${goto 20}${time %A}${goto 153}${color white}${time %H}:${time %M}
]];
-- https://store.kde.org/p/1197154/
```

Open a terminal and run `conky -c ~/.config/conky/conky.conf` and minimize all your open windows. Somewhere on your screen you'll see the following image:

[image: Clock on desktop]

---

Note that you want to make some changes:

- modify `own_window_colour = '252525'` to any other hex color you want. There's no need to include `#`.
- `gap_x = 100` positions the conky window 100px from the left of the screen. Change as per your needs.
- `gap_y = 200` positions the conky window 200px from the bottom of the screen. Change as per your needs.
- in the section "conky.txt", you can change the text color to your preference using hex colors as described above or color names as found in `/usr/share/X11/rgb.txt`.
- you can play with font and font size, voffset and what you want in terms of time formats (as described in `man date`).
- the line `own_window_type = 'desktop',` helps keep conky visible in Ubuntu 19.10 when minimizing all other open windows (aka Show Desktop) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Once, you're happy, you can get *conky* to run on startup by adding it to your distro's autostart.

---

Credit: code is based on [Conky Modern](https://store.kde.org/p/1197154/).

Comment: This is super nice, thanks a lot! one problem though.
When I use the show desktop key, it also takes away this widget. 
This is kind of a dealbreaker for me, is there a way to make conky stay?

Comment: I think the result may depend on your desktop environment but including `own_window_type = 'override',` may help. I've edited the code accordingly. If this solves your issue, please click the ✔ near the top left of the answer.

Comment: Got this in return:

conky: desktop window (800012) is subwindow of root window (140)
conky: window type - override
conky: drawing to created window (0x4200002)
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  1 (X_CreateWindow)
  Serial number of failed request:  96
  Current serial number in output stream:  100

Comment: I am using GNOME with Ubuntu 19.04 if that helps in the problemsolving. 

Thanks soo much for your time though <3

Comment: I use Kubuntu. Are you sure you included the `,`? Otherwise, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying with Ubuntu 19.10 (not 19.04). Changing `override` to `desktop` seems to work. Try that.

Comment: That did the trick :) superthanks a whole lot! you are fantastic!